# Why isn't my matplotlib animation working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot live prices of multiple stocks on the same plot. I am trying to adapt [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/animate_decay.html) animation example to do what I want with multiple lines, but I cannot get my code to plot and animate the data, despite prints showing that I am successfully retrieving the data I want. This is the code I have:

```
from itertools import count
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si


def price(symbols, lookback=5, legend=False, comparison=None, **pltkwargs):
    if isinstance(symbols, str):
        symbols = [symbols]
    times = [[] for symbol in symbols]
    prices = [[] for symbol in symbols]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    lines = [
        ax.plot(time_data, price_data, **pltkwargs)[0]
        for time_data, price_data in zip(times, prices)
    ]

    # def init():
    #     for line in lines:
    #         line.set_data([],[])
    #     return lines

    def animate(i):
        for count, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
            times[count].append(datetime.now())
            prices[count].append(float(si.get_live_price(symbol)))
            time_array = np.array(times[count])
            price_array = np.array(prices[count])
            back_time = time_array[-1] - timedelta(seconds=lookback)
            lines[count].set_data(
                time_array[time_array > back_time],
                price_array[time_array > back_time],
            )
        return lines

    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
    plt.show()
price(["MSFT", "AAPL"])
```

As far as I can tell this follows how animations are supposed to work: I update the artists and then return the artists that have changed. What am I missing?